# why the pyspark function is changing the data type of columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark

I am in a tricky situation.
I have two columns with `string type` and it is supposed to be `dateType` in the final path. So, to achieve that, I am passing it as a python dictionary

```
d = {"col1": DateType(), "col2": DateType()}
```

The above is passed to a data frame where I am supposed to do this transformation.

```
df = func.cast_attribute(df2, p_property.d)
```

The col1, and col2 are in the `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format. But as per the business requirement, I need the `"dd-mm-yyyy"` format. To do that I was suggested to use pyspark in-built function `date_format()`

```
col_df = df.withColumn("col1", date_format("col1", format="dd-MM-yyyy"))
```

But the problem is that the above transformation to convert `yyyy-MM-dd` to `dd-MM-yyyy` is converting the data type of the two cols back to string

Note
func.cast_attribute()

```
def cast_attribute(df, mapper={}):
    """ Cast columns of the dataframe \n
        Usage: cast_attribute(your_df, {'column_name', StringType()})
    Args:
        df (DataFrame):DataFrame to  convert some of the attributes.
        mapper (dict, optional): Dictionary with old column datatype to new datatype.
    Returns:
        DataFrame: Returns the dataframe with  converted  columns
    """
    for column, dtype in mapper.items():
        df = df.withColumn(column, col(column).cast(dtype))
    return df
```

Please suggest, how to keep the date type in the final data frame..

Comment: `yyyy-MM-dd` is the only format considered as date in pyspark. all others are considered strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A date object does not have a format attached to it. It is just a date. The format only makes sense when you want to print that date somewhere (console, text file...). In that case, spark needs to decide how to transform that date into a string before printing it. By default, spark uses its default format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Here is the documentation of `date_format`:

> Converts a date/timestamp/string to a value of **string** in the format specified by the date format given by the second argument.

Therefore, if you want to keep the date type, do not use `date_format`. If your problem is how the date is serialized when written to a CSV or a JSON file, you can configure the format with the `dateFormat` option of the `DataFrameWritter`.

```py
df = spark.range(1).withColumn("date", F.current_date())
df.write.option("dateFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy").csv("data.csv")
```

```
> cat data.csv/*
0,31-12-2022
```